# Long time ago I bound my right shift key to F3, how can I undo that?

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard

Basically, my shift key is being random. A long time ago, I set it to act like F3 (whatever that's called), and undid it. Now it's doing it again. How can I change it back to just shift? I can't seem to find the correct option in System Preferences>Keyboard>Keyboard shortcuts

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do that from Keyboard.prefPane. Are you sure you didn't use something like KeyRemap4MacBook?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, 
No I didn't use a remapper. However I did revert from lion to snow leopard and I believe the change was made in lion

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly as you described recently and you are right that there seems to be no trace to go back to that function to undo it. After talking to several Mac users, including store staff, it got resolved by trial and error by an Apple Store senior support person;
he expressed himself that it was an odd solution to the problem and that the key mapping may be faulty but it worked.

None of the people I talked to are aware of this capability to alter the function of the right shift key; if it wasn't for your post, they would have convinced me that there was no such function. Anyway, this is what he did:

- go to System Preferences, then Exposé/Spaces.
- in Exposé, for the "Application Windows" setting, choose "-"

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, `Shift` functions similarly to `Option` or `Command` in that they are modifier keys. You generally cannot assign a shortcut to just one of those keys. They must be used in concert with another (ie. `Shift + Option + X`).

Regardless of memory on how it was assigned, if it has reverted to incorrect function, and your keyboard is configured properly for QWERTY English, you may have a corrupted preferences file. The easiest way to determine how deep the issue runs is to test this in another User account.